# How do I prevent a div from breaking to the next page when using iText with XMLWorker?

Tags: itext

I'm using iText to generate a PDF file from my HTML templates. I have a list of `div`s that I want to be displayed without being split whenever possible. But I couldn't find a way to control this behavior when using `XMLWorker`. How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck - `<div>` is one of the two HTML tags that can apply the `page-break-inside: avoid` CSS style. Here's a working test case, first generate some test HTML:

```
public string GetHtml()
{
    var html = new StringBuilder();
    var repeatCount = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i) { html.Append("<h1>h1</h1>"); }

    var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer vestibulum sollicitudin luctus. Curabitur at eros bibendum, porta risus a, luctus justo. Phasellus in libero vulputate, fermentum ante nec, mattis magna. Nunc viverra viverra sem, et pulvinar urna accumsan in. Quisque ultrices commodo mauris, et convallis magna. Duis consectetur nisi non ultrices dignissim. Aenean imperdiet consequat magna, ac ornare magna suscipit ac. Integer fermentum velit vitae porttitor vestibulum. Morbi iaculis sed massa nec ultricies. Aliquam efficitur finibus dolor, et vulputate turpis pretium vitae. In lobortis lacus diam, ut varius tellus varius sed. Integer pulvinar, massa quis feugiat pulvinar, tortor nisi bibendum libero, eu molestie est sapien quis odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.";
    html.Append(text);
    for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i) 
    { 
        html.AppendFormat(
            "<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;>{0}</div>", 
            text
        ); 
    }
    return html.ToString();
}
```

Second, the simplest parsing implementation:

```
using (var html = new StringReader(GetHtml()))
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(
        OUTPUT_FILE,
        FileMode.Create,
        FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(
                document, stream
            );
            document.Open();
            XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
                writer, document, html
            );
        }
    }
}
```